# Nova posição X e Y a depender da direção e da distância?

Tags: c#, matemática, xna

Eu estou fazendo um mini jogo de tiro no XNA mas não estou conseguindo imaginar a forma de calcular o seguinte:

[image]

Sabendo a posição do centro da imagem, a direção na qual ele está apontando e a distância entre o centro e o "bico" da arma, como saber a posição X e Y do bico da arma?

Answer (score 3):

Achei a resposta:

```
newX = X + (raio) * cos⁡(ang);
newY = Y + (raio) * sin(ang);
```

Fonte: [Clique aqui](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1257345/caclulate-x-y-coordinates-of-point-after-rotation-around-another-point-of-given)